# How to connect Sitecore Rock to sitecore instance on docker?

Tags: sitecore-rocks, docker

How to connect Sitecore Rock to sitecore instance on docker ? 
does any one have experience ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't personally used it yet, but I was able to connect successfully Sitecore Rocks with a Sitecore instance running on a `cm` service container following these steps:

1) If not done yet, add a volume to your `cm` container service to map the container `C:\src` folder used by the `Watch-Directory` script to deploy files in the Sitecore instance. For example:

```
volumes:
      - .\deploy:C:\src
```

2) Manually create the following two folders in your host `deploy` folder: `bin` and `sitecore`. Sitecore Rocks validates their existance before installing the web service and the tool dlls used to communicate with the Sitecore instance.

[image]

3) In Visual Studio, create a new connection for Sitecore Rocks (the command is under `Extensions --> Sitecore --> New Connection...` in VS 2019), populating the following inputs:

- Host Name: the domain and port of your docker instance (ie. `localhost:44001`)
- Location: the path to the `deploy` folder (ie. `C:\Docker\docker-images\windows\tests\9.3.x\deploy`)

[image]

4) Click on the `Test` button. You might get a message saying that the website doesn't respond, asking if you want to start it without debugging. Select No.

[image]

5) A second message will ask you to update the server components. Select Yes.

[image]

6) A list of server components to update will be rendered, with a message alerting that the instance will be recycled due to the installation of new libraries. Select OK.

[image]

7) After the installation, you should get the confirmation message saying that the connection works:

[image]

The Sitecore Explorer will show the items in your Sitecore docker instance:

[image]

Comment: Great instructions. They worked perfectly. Thank you for sharing them.

Comment: My only contribution to this guide is the below link to how file deployment into running containers works. https://containers.doc.sitecore.com/docs/file-deployment